# Outline version of a Segoe MDL2 Assets symbol

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp, win-universal-app

As a new font technology, it appears that documentation for **Segoe MDL2 Assets** is incomplete, understandably because new symbols are being introduced from time to time. Quite by chance, I came across one symbol I was looking for -- a Feedback symbol with hexadecimal Unicode character code **E939** mentioned [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/monetize/launch-feedback-hub-from-your-app).

The Feedback symbol just referred to is a dark version, and what I am looking for is a light version, a.k.a Outline version. Some (if not most) Segoe MDL2 Assets symbols have both dark and light/outline versions and wondered if I missed this one for lack of complete documentation.

I searched and searched to no avail, and wondered if someone knows the code for an Outline version of the E939 symbol.

**Update [2016-10-03]**

Good news - Microsoft has at last released the icon I was looking for with hex code ED15. Check out [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/windows/uwp/style/segoe-ui-symbol-font). Thanks to @Jay - whose workaround suggestion kept me going until this solution arrived.

Comment: Where did you see the outlined E939 symbol? AFAIK, there is no outlined E939 symbol in Segoe MDL2 Assets symbol. You can use **Character Map** and select **Segoe MDL2 Assets** font to see all characters in this font.

Comment: I haven't seen the outlined version; I am simply asking if it exists and if so what the code is. I have gone thru the complete **Character Map** but no luck. Do you know where such requests can be made for MSFT to consider including an outline version (other than uservoice)? Thanks by the way.

Comment: You can also use **Windows Feedback** to send your feedback. Beside I do find a outlined version of the E939 symbol. However it's not in the official Segoe MDL2 Assets font. If you need it I can share it as a workaround.

Comment: Oops! By mistake I put my reply comment to you under the Answer below. --  I have used non-standard symbols without any trouble - for example, those you can access from [here](http://www.unicode.org/charts/) by using the 4 or even 5 hex code for the symbol which works fine as FontIcon glyph entity code in XAML. What do I need to do to get your help?

Comment: I've shared my workaround to use the outlined E939 symbol. Please have a check. And if you point over your comment you will see a "x" symbol after your comment. You can delete your comment by clicking it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As We've discussed in comments, there is no outline version of the E939 "Feedback" symbol in the official Segoe MDL2 Assets font.

However, when I searched on Internet, I do find the outline version in [Segoe MDL2 Assets - Cheatsheet](http://modernicons.io/segoe-mdl2/cheatsheet). To see this, please check "Show Legacy and Duplicates" on the page and search "E939".
[image]

After look at this web site's source code, I found it used WOFF 2.0 Web Font.

```css
@font-face {
    font-family: 'SegoeMDL2';
    src: url("fonts/segmdl2-webfont.woff2") format("woff2"), url("fonts/segmdl2-webfont.woff") format("woff");
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}
```

If I use the standard Segoe MDL2 Assets font, the E939  will still be solid.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <span style="font-family: 'Segoe MDL2 Assets'">&#xE939;</span>
</body>
</html>
```

So I used this WOFF 2.0 Web Font as a workaround to show the outlined E939 symbol.

In UWP, we can use custom font by setting [**FontFamily**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/windows.ui.xaml.media.fontfamily.aspx) property but woff2 file is not supported. I use [Online Font Converter](https://onlinefontconverter.com/) to convert woff2 file to ttf file. Once I get the ttf file, I put it into "Fonts" folder under the "Assets" folder. Then I can use the outlined E939 symbol like following:

```
<FontIcon x:Name="FeedbackIcon"
          FontFamily="ms-appx:///Assets/Fonts/SegoeMDL2Assets.ttf#Segoe MDL2 Assets"
          FontSize="60"
          Glyph="&#xE939;" />
```

And it looks like:
[image]

Comment: Thank you so much. You've done beyond the call of duty for developers like me by providing such a thought out workaround. Hope MSFT will provide a standard outline symbol. You're a star Jay.

Comment: Progress report: Works perfectly. Thanks again.

Comment: @user5525674, you're welcome. Glad to know it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting  `RequestedTheme="Dark"` on your control.

Comment: Okay, having tried what you suggest, I retract some of the remarks from above. Yes, this helps a bit by reversing the color but doesn't give me the Outline version I am looking for. I am hoping an Outline version exists hence for the symbol code if it exists.